# Prefix and Suffix tool for Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word, document, editing

I have a word document containing 1000 names. And I want them to be used in my code.

Document: ABC XYZ LMN

Final: "ABC", "XYZ", "LMN",

As you see, i want to prefix each name with **"** and suffix them with **",**

How to do it quickly??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the Find and Replace dialog (Ctrl+H) check `Use wildcards` option.

In the `Find what` enter `(<*>)`, in the `Replace with` enter `"\1",`, and click `Replace All`

http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 0):

@Slai ... Thanx, It worked.
But I also came up with a new way. 
I went to the find and replace dialog box and selected 'special' drop list. In it I selected whitespace and replaced it with ",". It worked for my document. 
But it may not work for those who don't have their words sorted with only 1 space btwn them.